# Does llvm support exception handling in WebAssembly?

Tags: clang, llvm, webassembly, specifications

The [Exception Handling Proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/exception-handling/blob/main/proposals/exception-handling/Exceptions.md) has been implemented in some environments, e.g. in [binaryen](https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen/blob/main/test/exception-handling.wast). But has it been implemented in llvm yet? Will llvm based compilers (with wasm as a target) like clang or emscripten generate code with try-catch blocks? (And where can such updated information be found in general for other proposals and instruction types as well?)

Comment: Are you asking whether a two- or three-line test program will compile and work?

Comment: I'm asking whether there exists code for which llvm would generate throw/try/catch wasm instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Wasm exception handling proposal is supported in the whole toolchain from llvm/clang, binaryen, and emscripten.

More info here: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/exceptions.html